# Enterprise Library 6.0 Configuration Console with Visual Studio 2015 does not contain Autoscaling Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2015, enterprise-library, wasabi

1) I downloaded the lastest .VSIX file that brings Enterprise Library Configuration Console 6.0 into Visual Studio 2015 (https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/enterpriselibrary-config-for-vs2015/)

2) In my Azure project, I downloaded nuget package - EnterpriseLibrary.Config.v6

3) I also downloaded the Autoscaler Enterprise Block (WASABi)

4) I also downloaded Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Azure

In my Azure project, when I right-click on the app.config file, I get the option of "Edit configuration file v6" and clicking on it, launches the "Enterprise Library Configuration Console v6" successfully.

However, this Config Console seems to be missing the Autoscale block.

How can I get it to add there? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it suits you, you could see if the v5 integrated editor works with VS2015: http://1drv.ms/1osGoER

Answer (score 0):

WASABi (Autoscaling Application Block) is not part of Enterprise Library 6 so the version 6 of the Enterprise Library Configuration Console does not container WASABi.

The v5 standalone editor should work.